# MongoDB data integrity on a create command with a preceeding validation command

Tags: c#, multithreading, mongodb, data-integrity

A website I'm creating lets users have a unique subdomain on the site eg; gaz123.mywebsite.com.

They enter their subdomain when they register on the site. In the code before I create the account record I check that the subdomain they've chosen doesn't already exist. This is just a simple query against accounts with the same subdomain. If this returns a zero count then I proceed and create the account with that subdomain.

I have placed a lock() command around the two MongoDB commands ie; check that the subdomain is available and then create the account. Then I release the lock.

```
lock( m_oLockMe)
{
    if( SubdomainIsFree( oRegisterModel.SubDomain))
    {
        CreateAccount( oRegisterModel);
    }
}
```

Is this how you would do it? Is there another way that is better? Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good way - you lose scalability here. I'd do this with atomic `findAndModify`. First you'll need to establish unique index on `subdomain` field:

```
db.subdomains.ensureIndex({subdomain: 1}, {unique: true})
```

This is needed for upsert to not generate duplicates. Then you'll do this:

```
r = db.subdomains.findAndModify({query: {used: false, subdomain: <subdomain>}, update: {$set: {used: true}}, new: true, upsert: true})
```

This will either return document which represents free subdomain or throw duplicate key error which means the subdomain is used. For free subdomain this will also atomically set `used` to `true` so it's guaranteed only a single `findAndModify` operation will get the same document.